# Pandas: [Errno 75] Value too large for defined data type

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having this strange error when converting a datetime column.

This is the offending line of code:

```
data['date'] = data['datetime'].map(lambda x:datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x/1000))
```

To make things more interesting this works:

```
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(data.datetime.max()/1000)
```

So the max value can be converted but for some other value I get a value too large for defined data type error.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit machine?

Comment: No, it's a 64b system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Pandas we can do it this way:

```
data['date'] = data['datetime'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9
```

that gives us a number of **seconds** since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

If you want/need to get # of **milliseconds**:

```
data['date'] = data['datetime'].astype(np.int64) // 10**6
```

---

Demo:

```
In [15]: data = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':pd.date_range('2000-01-01', freq='99D', periods=10)})

In [16]: data
Out[16]:
    datetime
0 2000-01-01
1 2000-04-09
2 2000-07-17
3 2000-10-24
4 2001-01-31
5 2001-05-10
6 2001-08-17
7 2001-11-24
8 2002-03-03
9 2002-06-10

In [17]: data['date'] = data['datetime'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9

In [18]: data
Out[18]:
    datetime        date
0 2000-01-01   946684800
1 2000-04-09   955238400
2 2000-07-17   963792000
3 2000-10-24   972345600
4 2001-01-31   980899200
5 2001-05-10   989452800
6 2001-08-17   998006400
7 2001-11-24  1006560000
8 2002-03-03  1015113600
9 2002-06-10  1023667200
```

Comment: Thanks, the conversion seems to work. I still don't know why the previous conversion failed with the value too large error.

Comment: @user3635284, i couldn't make `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(data.datetime.max()/1000)` work under Python 3.6 + Pandas 0.20.1. It gives me: `TypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp)`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a NaN inside your dataframe - computations with NaN won't be caught (as in x/1000), but when trying to convert it to a datetime object, it will throw the Value Too Large error. When you call max on the dataframe, it won't return NaN, which is why it works in that case.